# Debugging a Go project that builds using a makefile with Visual Studio Code

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, debugging, makefile, vscode-debugger

if you have experience with setting up debugging in VS Code for a Go project which uses a Makefile to build, could you please help and provide me some insight on this topic or configuration from launch.json file?

I have this [Go extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=golang.Go) already installed.

Example of `build` command in the makefile:

```
build:
    GOOS=linux  GOARCH=amd64 go build $(LDFLAGS) -o bin/broker-linux-amd64  cmd/integration-$(INTEGRATION_NAME)/main.go
    GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 go build $(LDFLAGS) -o bin/broker-darwin-amd64 cmd/integration-$(INTEGRATION_NAME)/main.go
    GOOS=darwin GOARCH=arm64 go build $(LDFLAGS) -o bin/broker-darwin-arm64 cmd/integration-$(INTEGRATION_NAME)/main.go
```

and also for `run` command which uses a few variables:

```
run:
    export ENVIRONMENT=xyz && \
    export HOST=https://example.com && \
    export USERNAME=xyz && \
    export PASSWORD=xyz && \
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add to your question what you've tried so far and how it failed.

Comment: @kristijan-maoduš I am also looking for the same thing. Did you succeed in setting up a debugger for this kind of setup? It'd be really helpful if you could share anything which worked.